spark dataframe to check if all the elements are matched to given value of particular column
I have created spark dataframe using scala, here is sample data
emp_id|result
1000  | [true,true,true]
1001  | [true,false,true]
1002  | [true,true,true]

result column is array
I would like to generate final dataframe to compare the all values with result column for a given value
If given value is true, then expecting out come should be
emp_id|result            | output
1000  | [true,true,true] | true
1001  | [true,false,true]| false
1002  | [true,true,true] | true

what is the better approach to achieve this using spark dataframe using scala.
I appreciate your help on this.

simple udf is sufficient for this kind of requrements. check my answer

Hi Were you able to check below answers ? is it working ?

If you are asking how to see if all items in result are true array_position would work:
import sparkSession.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val data = Seq(
  (Seq(true,false,true),
  Seq(true, true, true),
  Seq(false, false, false))).toDS

def allTrue(columnName: String) =
  (array_position($"$columnName", false) === 0).as(columnName)
  
data.select(
  allTrue("_1"), allTrue("_2"), allTrue("_3")
).show

yielding
+-----+----+-----+
|   _1|  _2|   _3|
+-----+----+-----+
|false|true|false|
+-----+----+-----+

any false value would imply false.
If this is not what you are looking for, perhaps it's a general test framework across all fields check out Quality.  If it's something else altogether please show what you have tried.

Simple way is use  udf function to check if all elements in the array are true
Scala Spark Users:
Use Spark version 3.1.1
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}
    
    object TruthCheckApp {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val spark = SparkSession.builder()
          .appName("TruthCheckApp")
          .master("local[*]")
          .getOrCreate()
    
        import spark.implicits._
    
        // your data
        val data = Seq(
          (1000, Array(true, true, true)),
          (1001, Array(true, false, true)),
          (1002, Array(true, true, true))
        )
    
 
      val df = data.toDF("emp_id", "result")
     
        val allTrue: UserDefinedFunction = udf((arr: Seq[Boolean]) => arr.forall(_ == true))
 
    val dfWithOutput = df.withColumn("output", allTrue(col("result")))
 
    dfWithOutput.show(truncate = false)
 
    spark.stop()
 }
}


output log :
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
24/06/12 21:49:06 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.1.1
24/06/12 21:49:07 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
24/06/12 21:49:07 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
24/06/12 21:49:07 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
24/06/12 21:49:07 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: TruthCheckApp
24/06/12 21:49:07 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 1024, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
24/06/12 21:49:07 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpu
24/06/12 21:49:07 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0

....

+------+-------------------+------+
|emp_id|result             |output|
+------+-------------------+------+
|1000  |[true, true, true] |true  |
|1001  |[true, false, true]|false |
|1002  |[true, true, true] |true  |
+------+-------------------+------+

Pyspark Users :
udffunction to check if all elements in the array are true
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType


def main():
    # Initialize Spark session
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("TruthCheckApp") \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .getOrCreate()

    data = [
        (1000, [True, True, True]),
        (1001, [True, False, True]),
        (1002, [True, True, True])
    ]

    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["emp_id", "result"])

    all_true_udf = udf(all_true, BooleanType())
    df_with_output = df.withColumn("output", all_true_udf(col("result")))
    df_with_output.show(truncate=False)
    spark.stop()

def all_true(arr):
        return all(arr)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Same as above scala output :
24/06/13 14:00:36 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped
+------+-------------------+------+
|emp_id|result             |output|
+------+-------------------+------+
|1000  |[true, true, true] |true  |
|1001  |[true, false, true]|false |
|1002  |[true, true, true] |true  |
+------+-------------------+------+


Process finished with exit code 0

